# Looking for the first underscore then find the 5th space after

Tags: t-sql, substring, wildcard, charindex

I am trying to create a filter where I am looking for the first (or last) occurrence of an underscore (or it can be any character) and then start from there to look for the 5th character.

I am thinking of something along the lines of either right or left char index picking a side to start on. Really trying to look for a good explanation of why your answer is written in that manner.

Example: I am looking for __poptarts_________.

So I would want it to start at the leftmost _ and search for the 5th character after that (p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by using both `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`

`SELECT SUBSTRING (string,(CHARINDEX('_',string,0)+1),5)`

In your case which would be:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING ('I am looking for __poptarts_________',(CHARINDEX('_','I am looking for __poptarts_________',0)+1),5)
```

Result is  `_popt` because you put two '_' before 'p'

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I am trying to do the exact same thing, but now I want to filter out these results in the where clause. What approach would I take.

Comment: not a problem, what do you mean 'filter out'? did you mean you do not want to get the result that contain '_popt' ?

Comment: Actually going through your answer again, I may have asked my question wrong but instead of the result returning _popt, I just want it to return one character, let's say 't' (5th from the first _). Then I would only want results where is not like [A-Z]

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING ('I am looking for __poptarts_________',(CHARINDEX('_','I am looking for __poptarts_________',0)+5),1)

Comment: You better know what does each number mean in the query then you could apply to each case, and btw what do you mean not like [A-Z], i see no others but characters. Could you specify your question again?